# Deleting an instance based on user input?

Tags: ruby

i've went through about 15 similar questions and haven't yet found one that answered mine properly, so i thought it might warrant a new thread.

I'm making a ruby terminal app for a game, and I'm trying to give the user the option to delete a sword of his choice based on their text input. This is what i have so far.

```
class Weapon
    attr_reader :weapon_name, :grip, :guard, :blade
    attr_accessor :strength, :speed, :defence, :ascii_image

    SWORDS = []

    def initialize(weapon_name, grip, guard, blade)
        @weapon_name = weapon_name
        @strength = 0
        @speed = 0
        @defence = 0
        self.grip = grip
        self.guard = guard
        self.blade = blade
        self.ascii_image = ascii_image
        SWORDS << self
    end

...

    Weapon.new("Epic Sword", "straight", "forward", "narrow")

    def self.delete
        puts "Which weapon would you like to delete?"
        delete_target = gets.chomp.downcase.strip
        SWORDS.delete_if{@weapon_name == delete_target}
        puts SWORDS
    end
end
```

The above method for some reason seems to delete *every* sword in the array and ONLY IF delete_target is = to the last item in the array. (Otherwise it seems to do nothing) What am i doing wrong here? How can i target a specific sword by its @weapon_name?

Comment: There's some weirdness here, but you need to be looking at the name of *each sword in the array*. The name is an instance priperty of an instancr, you do not reference an instance, and instead introduce an instance properry of the class *itself*.

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question, i kind of get what you mean but where am i doing that? Is it because of the 'self' before delete or is something else referencing the class itself?

Comment: [`delete_if`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-delete_if) will yield each "Weapon" to the block you need to use this "piped" local variable to match against your target. `SWORDS.delete_if{ |w| w.weapon_name.downcase == delete_target}`

Comment: "delete" is a class method--not tied to an *instance* of that class. One rrason it's weird is becaise you're conflating "a weapon" (an instance of Weapon) with a collection of weapons. This (maybe) isn't fundamentally bad, but it could cause confusion. "delete_if" yields each object (here an instance of "Weapon") and its that instance's name you should be testing against.

Answer (score 0):

You seem confused about what each object is. Let's recap:

```
epic_sword = Weapon.new("Epic Sword", "straight", "forward", "narrow")
```

The `epic_sword` object is an instance of `Weapon`.

As a *side-effect* of initialising this, you also updated `Weapon::SWORDS` to contain this object.

---

```
    puts "Which weapon would you like to delete?"
    delete_target = gets.chomp.downcase.strip
```

`delete_target` is a **`String`**, e.g `"epic sword"`. It is only the (lower-case) *name* of the sword, not the weapon object itself.

---

```
SWORDS.delete_if{@weapon_name == delete_target}
```

This line doesn't make sense. For one thing, `@weapon_name` is undefined; you're inside a class method, not within a `Weapon` instance. And as stated above, the `delete_target` is only a `String`, so won't be *equal* to the weapon object.

To fix this, you can do:

```
SWORDS.delete_if{ |sword| sword.weapon_name.downcase == delete_target}
```

Comment: Thanks Tom i think i'm understanding what you're saying - but it's still not working for some reason. Very frustrating, been stuck on this same silly problem all night

Comment: What do you mean by "It's not working"? You haven't shown us a reproducible code sample (there's a mysterious `...` in the middle, which I'm suspicious about), and you haven't show us an error message.

Comment: I'm actually quite confused where this `def self.delete` method is being defined... Is that inside the `Weapon` class, or somewhere else??!

Comment: You're right sorry, there is no error when delete is called - however any swords you attempt to delete will still be there afterwards. Also, yeah self.delete is inside the Weapon class, just realized i didn't make that clear my bad. I could show you the entire code, but it's quite lengthy and unrelated (as far as i can tell).

Comment: I've got a solution Tom! It turns out that because I was using a gem to add colours to weapon_name, it was changing it's value and that's why your code wasn't working. I had no idea the gem would do that, and because I was only using puts SWORDS instead of p SWORDS to test it, it wasn't giving me the right information.

Comment: @zedd0 Ahh - So in other words, `delete_target` was not actually equal to any sword name? :D As another suggestion, you could try changing your program design slightly: First *print all the swords*, and ask the user which one they want to delete! The user enters a *number*, and you delete that number from the list. It's totally unambiguous that way.